# How to fill the column values from server side in Ember

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I am using **ember-cli**. I want to create a record for a route `students` which has the details of students(say 'Name','Age','Marks'). I will get two values from UI('Name','Age') and I have to return a value from server side('Marks').

My code in controller of `students.new` is:

```
var newStudent = this.store.createRecord('student', { Name:'XYZ', Age: '20' });
newStudent.save();
this.transitionToRoute('students');
```

My code in template of 'students' is:

```
{{#each student in model}}
<tr>
    <td>{{student.Name}}</td>
    <td>{{student.Age}}</td>
    <td>{{student.Marks}}</td>
</td>
{{/each}}
```

But after saving, in `students` only two values that I gave in UI only came. The value I returned from server side was not updated. It is loaded only when the page is reloaded.

**How can I do it without reloading the page?**

Answer (score 0):

Ember is a client side framework. Assuming your confused and have the mark do this:

```
newStudent.set('Marks',marks)
newStudent.save();
this.transitionToRoute('students');
```

Comment: I have to get marks at server side only. For example I have to query it from data table.

Comment: Well what's your backend? Assuming you don't even need to pass in marks you can just add it to your new function server side

Comment: My backend is a servlet that stores data into a table. I will show the data from the table in 'students'. Here the value of 'Marks' is obtained only from the servelet. But I cant show its value in 'students'.